# Which user information is provided by twitter after social media login?

Tags: twitter, social-media

I want the user information when he/she is login through his/her twitter(social media) account. Please help me to get that which user details are provided by twitter?

Comment: I have researched on that and i get that twitter only provides username, firstname, lastname and some basic information about user not his/her email.